# Implement trie data structure by dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, trie

To implement trie from dict in python, first I try to understand other's code:

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = {}
    def insert(self, word: str) -> None:
        node = self.t
        for c in word:
            if c not in node:
                node[c] = {}
            node = node[c]
            print(node)
        node['-'] = True
```

And I call the function 'insert' by

```
d = Trie()
d.insert("word")
d.insert("welcome")
d.insert("what")
```

The results are

```
{}
{}
{}
{}
{'o': {'r': {'d': {'-': True}}}}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{'o': {'r': {'d': {'-': True}}}, 'e': {'l': {'c': {'o': {'m': {'e': {'-': True}}}}}}}
{}
{}
{}
```

I am confused about the results especially the nonempty ones. How does the code `node = node[c]` work to get such results?

Comment: `node` initially was set to the root, `c` would be a character currently being checked, `node = node[c]` simply updates the `node` assignment to the existing or newly created `dict` for the character `c`.

Comment: To better understand this function, replace `print(node)` with `print(self.t)` so you can see how the data structure is built as the string is iterated over.  The current impl prints the newly added empty dict each time instead of the completed structure.